# Is it possible to create a variable that can be also used in other different templates in XSLT 3.0?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have started to research on main changes in XSLT 3.0. As far as I know, in XSLT 2.0 we are not able to create a global variable to use in different templates.

With the Streaming mode in XLST 3.0 and xsl:iterate function or higher-order function or some other abilities we are now able to "remember" the values from the previous functions and therefore, We can use the values in different places over and over again.

My question relies on this basic example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PERSONAE PLAY="OTHELLO">
    <TITLE>Dramatis Personae</TITLE>
    <PERSON>
        <NAME>DUKE OF VENICE</NAME>
        <ID>123456</ID>
        <PROPERTIES>
            <BIRTHDAY>10.10.1980</BIRTHDAY>
            <CITY>New York</CITY>
            <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
        </PROPERTIES>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON>
        <NAME>BRABANTIO, a senator.</NAME>
        <ID>123456</ID>
        <PROPERTIES>
            <BIRTHDAY>10.10.1980</BIRTHDAY>
            <CITY>New York</CITY>
            <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
        </PROPERTIES>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON>
        <NAME>Other Senators.</NAME>
        <ID>123456</ID>
        <PROPERTIES>
            <BIRTHDAY>10.10.1980</BIRTHDAY>
            <CITY>New York</CITY>
            <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
        </PROPERTIES>
    </PERSON>
</PERSONAE>
```

Let's say that it is my xml example and i want to change this  values with unique ID's generated by java:util function

The XSLT is :

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:util="java:java.util.UUID"
  version="3.0" expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="PERSONAE"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:call-template name="birthdayTemplate"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="PERSONAE">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>The Cast of {@PLAY}</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TITLE">
    <h1>{.}</h1>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PERSON/NAME[count(tokenize(., ',') = 2)]">
    <p><b>{substring-before(., ',')}</b>: {substring-after(., ',')}</p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PERSON/NAME">
    <p>
      <b>{.}</b>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="PERSON/ID">

    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="util:toString(util:randomUUID())"/>
    </p>

  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="PERSON/PROPERTIES"></xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="birthdayTemplate">

  <xsl:for-each select="PERSON/PROPERTIES">
      <PROPERTIES>
        <ID>THE UUID VALUE THAT IS CREATED IN THE RESULT DOCUMENT</ID>
      </PROPERTIES>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result I wish to have is:

```
<html xmlns:util="java:java.util.UUID">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>The Cast of OTHELLO</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Dramatis Personae</h1>

      <p><b>DUKE OF VENICE</b></p>

      <p>a6759c7b-ff13-4b27-b726-ecd6ebaea96c</p>



      <p><b>BRABANTIO, a senator.</b></p>

      <p>1a58c699-ee9e-4093-8224-5319127fbf8c</p>



      <p><b>Other Senators.</b></p>

      <p>482908c6-2437-406d-a421-c7d2a103aba7</p>


      <p>
         <PROPERTIES>
            <ID>a6759c7b-ff13-4b27-b726-ecd6ebaea96c</ID>
            <BIRTHDAY>10.10.1980</BIRTHDAY>
            <CITY>New York</CITY>
            <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
         </PROPERTIES>
      </p>
      <p>
         <PROPERTIES>
            <ID>1a58c699-ee9e-4093-8224-5319127fbf8c</ID>
            <BIRTHDAY>10.10.1980</BIRTHDAY>
            <CITY>New York</CITY>
            <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
         </PROPERTIES>
      </p>
      <p>
         <PROPERTIES>
            <ID>482908c6-2437-406d-a421-c7d2a103aba7</ID>
            <BIRTHDAY>10.10.1980</BIRTHDAY>
            <CITY>New York</CITY>
            <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
         </PROPERTIES>
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

As you can see from the xml example, the ID's of the PERSON nodes are the same, to fix this problem, I decided to use random uuid generator to assing different id's to all persons node, so therefore they can have be identified uniquely.

My other intention is to create another template for different properties of the PERSON node and connect these properties with the same unique ID.

The question is: Is there any way in XSLT 3.0 (or if there is in XSLT 2.0 but priority is 3.0) to read these random uuid's before it is shown(or I dont know how it is processed) and use the same values in different place respect to recursive matching ?

**EDIT:** I fixed the problem by creating another XSLT transformation, which just changes the  values with random UUID's and then in the second transformation, I copy the values. What if it is possible in one single transformation with XSLT 3.0, with  streamable mode ? or  ? or something else? I understand your answer @Tomalak but I just want to know If any other way exists to fix this problem ?

Comment: *"As far as I know, in XSLT 2.0 we are not able to create a global variable to use in different templates."* This is false. You can create a global variable, just use `<xsl:variable>` as a child of `<xsl:stylesheet>`. This has been so since XSLT 1.0. What you *cannot* do is make a variable that belongs to one template visible in a different template, and this has not changed in XSLT 3.0 (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#scope-of-variables). If you want to pass a value to a template, use `<xsl:param>` and `<xsl:with-param>`.

Comment: Also, the `<xsl:template name="Properties">` is never called in your example.

Comment: Sorry for the quality of example, I understand what you mean, and you are absolutely right, calling template is not a problem, It wasnt my main concern. What i try to ask is, How to get the values of random UUID's recursively for each different UUID and write them into new node (like <ID-REFERENCE>) to create a semantic reference to <ID>value to match. Is this allowed in XSLT 2.0 ? If so how? and more like I would like to learn the new functionalities of XSLT 3.0 to do it. Thank you !

Comment: Read the last sentence of my first comment again. The way of getting values into templates has not changed since XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @Sojimanatsu - It would probably help if you edited your question and showed your expected output as it may be the problem you are actually trying to solve does not need the use of parameters or variables at all. Thank you.

Comment: As @TimC suggests...please provide fuller background such as desired output. Otherwise this reads as the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Accepted answer uses the example of a question: *Is there a function to return a string between two delimiters?* when really the question is how to parse json!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a global, defined like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="idrefs">
  <xsl:for-each select="//PERSON">
      <PERSON newid="id_{position()}">
          <ID>{generate-id(ID)}</ID>
      </PERSON>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

(I'm using `position()` here to generate a new ID just to demonstrate)

Then, if you define a key like this...

```
<xsl:key name="idrefs" match="PERSON" use="ID" />
```

You can get the new id like this (assuming you are positioned on an old ID node)

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('idrefs', generate-id(), $idrefs)/@newid"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:util="java:java.util.UUID"
  expand-text="yes">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="PERSONAE"/>

  <xsl:variable name="idrefs">
      <xsl:for-each select="//PERSON">
          <PERSON newid="id_{position()}">
              <ID>{generate-id(ID)}</ID>
          </PERSON>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:key name="idrefs" match="PERSON" use="ID" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PERSONAE">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>The Cast of {@PLAY}</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:call-template name="birthdayTemplate"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TITLE">
    <h1>{.}</h1>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PERSON/NAME[count(tokenize(., ',') = 2)]">
    <p><b>{substring-before(., ',')}</b>: {substring-after(., ',')}</p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PERSON/NAME">
    <p>
      <b>{.}</b>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PERSON/ID">
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="key('idrefs', generate-id(), $idrefs)/@newid"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PERSON/PROPERTIES"></xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="birthdayTemplate">
    <xsl:for-each select="PERSON/PROPERTIES">
      <PROPERTIES>
        <ID>{key('idrefs', generate-id(../ID), $idrefs)/@newid}</ID>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
      </PROPERTIES>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect! I just changed the id_{position()} with {util:toString(util:randomUUID())} and it works as expected. So here there is nothing special to xslt 3.0 ? Can also be done in 2.0 right?

Comment: I believe Text Value Templates are xslt 3.0 only, so you would have to change `<ID>{key('idrefs', generate-id(../ID), $idrefs)/@newid}</ID>` to `<ID><xsl:value-of select="key('idrefs', generate-id(../ID), $idrefs)/@newid" /></ID>`, but apart from that it should work in XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 1):

The real issue in these examples is side-effects. The function `util:randomUUID()` is not a pure function, because it returns a different value each time. Calls to such functions are very implementation dependent, whether you're using XSLT 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

XSLT 3.0 gives you some additional tools to help in tackling this problem. There's `fn:random-number-generator()` which enables you to generate random numbers in a pure-functional approach. There's also annotations on user-defined functions (`cache=yes/no`, `new-each-time=yes/no/maybe`) which allow you to give directions to the processor as to how it should handle repeated calls on the same function. But it remains true that the semantics of the language are fuzzy round the edges when you start calling external methods that have side-effects.